# Multilingual support in website

Tags: multilingual

I am using SP2013 & I want to create multilingual support for my current SP site , Is there any way except google translate ? any other plug-in or anything ?

Answer (score 7):

SharePoint has a default multilingual features. In this [post](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-multilingual-features-53411469-53e3-4570-95e2-3651f166174f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) you got a review about the feature. Even you can enable the option for user to chose their language on their interface.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint 2013 Variations for multilingual website. Please have a look at following articles:

[Variations overview in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628966.aspx)

[Technical: Initial Setup and Configuration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/12/sharepoint-2013-variations-creating-site-and-variation-labels.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to required in order to create the multilingual sites.

- You have to install the SharePoint Language Packs for each additional Language.This is server level Activity, required the Downtime, as you have to run the PSconfig Wizard after installation of LPs to update the Schema.[Install or uninstall language packs for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108.aspx)
- Now you can create a new site collection in other language but Keep in mind you can't change the language of existing site collection.
- or You can use Variations as other folks mentioned in their responses.